# If I want 2 css framework like bootstrapvue & vuetify use same project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I want 2 CSS framework use my existing nuxtjs project - anyone questions why to use 2 CSS framework one vuejs project -

answer this question - I want, my website web version and mobile version, i use web version is boostrapvue its awsome for web version - or vuetfy is the better mobile version.

anyone plz help, it's possible

Comment: The same goal you can achieve by one!

Comment: I recommend that you use only one framework. But if you want to use both, I recommend that you create two sub-domains with two differents apps.

Comment: But quora.com - use one domain and run 2 projects ` mobile & web version -  one domain, not use sub domains.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, you can use both the frameworks easily. But the problems include clashing of css classes. Although both have different components, they can still lead to some unexpected design. I would recommend using a single css framework, but if you are adamant about using two CSS frameworks, it is not a heck. Just install both these libraries and include in main.js/app.js file.

***For bootstrap vue,***

```
npm install vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap
```

***For vuetify,***

```
vue add vuetify
```

Then include in your main.js/app.js using,

```
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: but I have a problem. i use boostrapvue code or vuetfy code - some code matching the boostrapvue  from vuetfy codes - its problem our project. its solution